# Chi square reporting df for 2x1

Tags: chi-squared-test, degrees-of-freedom

I conducted a 2x1 chi square and need to report it in APA. There are 280 in the sample. Do I deduct the df from the sample size? e.g. X2 (1, N=279)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have $280$ observations, so you start off with $280$ degrees of freedom. Then you calculate the proportion of observations that belong to one group vs the other. This eats a degree of freedom, leaving you with $279$. Next, you calculate the proportion of observations that belong to the other group, but, because probabilities add up to one, this is implied by the earlier calculation, and you do not need to eat another degree of freedom. Your intuition guided you to the right answer of $279$ degrees of freedom.

Perhaps APA has this standard, but I do not like the idea of reporting `N = 279`. This suggests that your sample size was `279`, which is false. However, if readers know this means the degrees of freedom instead of the actual sample size, then you are communicating the correct information. (That I do not get the notation is a Dave problem, not a you problem.)